# Question about finitely generated k-algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm studying the Milne's Algebraic geometry, p.194, Lemma 9.3

[image]

[image]

I can't understand the underlined statements

Q. first question : Why $A[T]/\mathfrak{a'} = A[t'] $ for some $t' \in B'$?  What $t'$ can be? I suspect $t' = T + \mathfrak {a'}$. Is it true?

Q. Second question : why such $c\in k$ exists?'

My first attempt : If $ \tilde{\alpha}(\{h'(T) : h \in \mathfrak{a}\}) \subseteq k[T]$ does not contain a nonzero constant, then it generates a proper ideal in $k[T]$. So by the Hilbert Nullstellenstaz, the ideal has a zero $c$ in $k$. So for all $h(T) = c_{r}T^{r} + \cdots c_{0} \in \mathfrak{a}$, $$ \tilde{\alpha}(h')(c) = \alpha(c_{r}) + \alpha(c_{r-1})c + \cdots + \alpha(c_{0})c^{r}=0 $$.

So it suffices to show that $ D := \tilde{\alpha}(\{h'(T) : h \in \mathfrak{a}\}) \subseteq k[T]$ does not contain a nonzero constant.

By the way of contradiction, assume that there exists $ 0\neq l \in k$ such that $l\in D$. Then
there exists $h(T) = c_{r}T^{r} + \cdots c_{0} \in \mathfrak{a}$ such that $\tilde{\alpha}(h'(T))=l$, which means that $\alpha(c_{r}) + \alpha(c_{r-1})T + \cdots + \alpha(c_{0})T^{r}=l \neq0$.

So, $\alpha(c_{r}) = l \neq 0  (\Rightarrow c_{r} \neq 0) $, and $\alpha(c_{r-1}) = \cdots = \alpha(c_{0}) = 0 $. Since we have extended homomorphism $\hat{\alpha} : B':= A[T]/\mathfrak{a'} \to k$  of  $\alpha$, it means

$$\hat{\alpha}(c_{r}  + \mathfrak{a'}) = l \neq 0,    \hat{\alpha}(c_{r-1}  + \mathfrak{a'}) = \cdots = \hat{\alpha}(c_{0}  + \mathfrak{a'}) =0 $$

Now, "**if $c_{r-1}, \cdots c_{0} \in \mathfrak{a'} $** , then since $\mathfrak{a'}$ does not contain nonzero constants, $c_{r-1}, \cdots c_{0} = 0$ and so we obtain a nonzero polynomial $h(T) = c_{r}T^{r} \in \mathfrak{a}$ which is a contradiction to "$\mathfrak{a'}$ does not contain a nonzero constant" ($\because$ $\mathfrak{a'}$ contains a nonzero constant if and only if $\mathfrak{a}$ contains a nonzero polynomial $cT^{r}$.)

But "$c_{r-1}, \cdots c_{0} \in \mathfrak{a'}$ " is true? More generally, if $\hat{\alpha}(c + \mathfrak{a'}) = 0 $ for some $c \in A$, then $c\in \mathfrak{a'}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: $t'=\mathfrak{a}+T$ as you suspected.

Q2: $c\in k$ is just the image of $T$ under the extended map $\alpha: B'\to k $.

Comment: Ok. Such $c$ works! It was a simpler choice than I expected.  Thank you. :)